# Is the use of * allowed in Snakemake?

Tags: python, shell, glob, snakemake

I need to concatenate certain files inside some directories that have been created using a wildcard in a `Snakefile`. I tried to create the following rule to concatenate all files inside these directories:

```py
# concatenate output per hmm
rule concatenate:
    input:
        output_{hmm}/* ,
    output: 
        output_{hmm}/cat_{hmm}.txt,
    params:
        cmd='cat'
    shell: 
        '{params.cmd} {input} > {output} '
```

It doesn't work and produced the following error:

```
"SyntaxError in line 62 of /scratch/data1/agalvez/domains/Snakefile_ecdf:
invalid syntax (Snakefile_ecdf, line 62)"
```

I do not know what is wrong with the rule and I suppose that the use of `*` might not be adequate, but I cannot think of another way to do what I intend to.

EDIT:
The question might be lacking some information so I will also attach the complete Snakefile:

```
ARCHIVE_FILE = 'output.tar.gz'

# a single output file
OUTPUT_FILE = 'output_{hmm}/{species}_{hmm}.out'

# a single input file
INPUT_FILE = 'proteins/{species}.fasta'

# a single hmm file
HMM_FILE = 'hmm/{hmm}.hmm'

# a single cat file
CAT_FILE = 'cat/cat_{hmm}.txt'

# Build the list of input files.
INP = glob_wildcards(INPUT_FILE).species

# Build the list of hmm files.
HMM = glob_wildcards(HMM_FILE).hmm

# The list of all output files
OUT = expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm=HMM)

# The list of all CAT files
CAT = expand(CAT_FILE, hmm=HMM)

# pseudo-rule that tries to build everything.
# Just add all the final outputs that you want built.
rule all:
    input: ARCHIVE_FILE

# hmmsearch
rule hmm:
    input:
        species=INPUT_FILE ,
        hmm=HMM_FILE
    output: 
        OUTPUT_FILE,
    params:
        cmd='hmmsearch --noali -E 99 --tblout'
    shell: 
        '{params.cmd} {output} {input.hmm} {input.species} '

# concatenate output per hmm
from glob import glob

rule concatenate:
    input:
        files = glob("output_{hmm}/*") ,
    output: 
        CAT_FILE,
    params:
        cmd='cat'
    shell: 
        '{params.cmd} {input.files} {output} '

# create an archive with all results
rule create_archive:
    input: OUT, CAT,
    output: ARCHIVE_FILE
    shell: 'tar -czvf {output} {input}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes, let's create a sample file set (so operating with dummy files to make sure the workflow works).  In the terminal, I ran:

```sh
mkdir proteins && touch proteins/1.fasta proteins/2.fasta
mkdir hmm && touch hmm/A.hmm hmm/B.hmm
```

Now, your workflow is mostly correct, except for the rule `concatenate`. The inputs for this rule are created by rule `hmm`, and the output of this rule is specific to wildcard value of `hmm`. So you are interested in all values for `species` for a given `hmm`. The way to get that is to use `expand` but keep `hmm` in wildcard format, using `expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm="{hmm}")`:

```py
rule concatenate:
    input:
        expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm="{hmm}"),
    output:
        CAT_FILE,
    params:
        cmd="cat",
    shell:
        "{params.cmd} {input} > {output} "
```

In the workflow below I modified rule `hmm` for quick test run, so the complete workflow will look like this:

```py
ARCHIVE_FILE = "output.tar.gz"

# a single output file
OUTPUT_FILE = "output_{hmm}/{species}_{hmm}.out"

# a single input file
INPUT_FILE = "proteins/{species}.fasta"

# a single hmm file
HMM_FILE = "hmm/{hmm}.hmm"

# a single cat file
CAT_FILE = "cat/cat_{hmm}.txt"

# Build the list of input files.
INP = glob_wildcards(INPUT_FILE).species

# Build the list of hmm files.
HMM = glob_wildcards(HMM_FILE).hmm

# The list of all output files
OUT = expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm=HMM)

# The list of all CAT files
CAT = expand(CAT_FILE, hmm=HMM)


# pseudo-rule that tries to build everything.
# Just add all the final outputs that you want built.
rule all:
    input:
        ARCHIVE_FILE,


# hmmsearch
rule hmm:
    input:
        species=INPUT_FILE,
        hmm=HMM_FILE,
    output:
        touch(OUTPUT_FILE),
    params:
        #        cmd='hmmsearch --noali -E 99 --tblout'
        cmd="echo",
    shell:
        "{params.cmd} {output} {input.hmm} {input.species} "


rule concatenate:
    input:
        expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm="{hmm}"),
    output:
        CAT_FILE,
    params:
        cmd="cat",
    shell:
        "{params.cmd} {input} > {output} "


# create an archive with all results
rule create_archive:
    input:
        CAT,
    output:
        ARCHIVE_FILE,
    shell:
        "tar -czvf {output} {input}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried copying your 'rule concatenate' and it still gives me the error message 'Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).' I solved it by "touching" the hmm input files, but I still do not understand why it was not generating the cat files when they did not exist. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your initial cat command did not contain ">" symbol, which is needed to save the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Snakefile is Python code and as such all the file references should be strings/path-like objects (or variables/functions that return such objects). However, in general input files should be specific files, rather than directories.

There are several ways out of this, one of which is to glob files inside python and pass them explicitly:

```py
from glob import glob

rule concatenate:
    input:
        files = glob("output_{hmm}/*") ,
    output: 
        combined = "output_{hmm}/cat_{hmm}.txt",
    params:
        cmd='cat'
    shell: 
        '{params.cmd} {input.files} {output.combined} '
```

Note that as it stands this rule is going to cause problem on repeated runs, since the concatenated file ("output_{hmm}/cat_{hmm}.txt") is going to be globbed on a repeated run.

Comment: First fo all thank you for your quick response and your help. If I created a new directory to store the concatenated files, would it solve the probem? So, instead of using "output_{hmm]/cat_{hmm}.txt" as my output option, I could use "concatenated_files/cat_{hmm}.txt". Would this work?

Comment: You are welcome, yes, that would work.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering and thanks again. I tried what you proposed but Snakemake tells me that there is Nothing to be done, as if the files already existed (but they do not exist). "Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).".

Comment: Interesting, are files in "output_{hmm}/*" generated by another rule? If so, a different approach is needed.

Comment: Yes, they are! Sorry for not clarifying this previously. I will edit the original question to show the complete content of the Snakefile.